# Reduce url parameters to integer or hexadecimal short

Tags: php, url

i need to make my url shorter .
The url give parameters that fill a form with all these values.

**example.com/module-name-par1-par2-par3-par4....-par19**

I need something like this :
**example.com/module-name-3456de34567**

I've tried base64_encode ... but the result is too large.
The function md5 , crypt, hash ... are too complex for my needs...
There is no need to crypt data, because it's a part of my configuration , just need url shorter.

Important : I do not want to use a database...

**EDIT #1** : par1,..,par19  are only letter or integer with for some parameters hexa color, that's all and they instanciate elements in a form.
The max string lenght = 10 for a parameter.
sometime i only use par1,...par5

I do not want to use **POsT** in order to avoid page refresh, 
and i need to send the url to people that work with me...

What i've got :
**example.com/module-name-51-8-3cb371-example-dddcdc-696969-on-a-FFFFFF-3cb371-backend1**

I've tried to change each letter, number to Ascii but it was not reduced...

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Can you describe your use case or give a more detailed example? What's inside the url parameters? Key-Value-Pairs?

Comment: Pass there data in a POST, not in the URL, you will have a shorter URL and a more secure transfer. Base64 increases the length by 33%, md5 and hash do not allow retrieving the original data and encryption does not shorten data. There are compression functions but then that output would need to e URL encoded.

Comment: Could you adapt your logic so that all letters can be capitals (or all lowercase)?

Comment: @trincot yes all letters can be lowercase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If base64 encoding is still too long then there is not much gain you can get from other encodings as the URI characters you can use without percent-escapes is very limited. And obviously using percent-escapes will make the URL longer instead of shorter, so you'll want to avoid those.

But chances are that you could shorten the length of the non-encoded data. Here are some things you could do:

- Color codes can represent 2<sup>24</sup> (~ 16 million) different colors. Are *all* these colors really a potential candidate for a parameters value? Probably not. You could for instance give up some precision by coding your colors with only 3 hexadecimal characters instead of 6, like can also be done in CSS. Then FFF is equivalent to FFFFFF and 969 is 996699. This still allows for 4000 different colors. If you intend to use only a few different colors, then the following idea could also be used for them:
- names and other words (like "example", "on", "a", and "backend1") will not be completely random. You would probably never define one of these parameters as "xqzIJ4". Possibly you have a limited set of possible words that can occur in a certain argument. Make a comprehensive list of those and give them a sequential number (1, 2, ...) and pass that number (in hexadecimal notation) instead of the word.
- Encode integer arguments in hexadecimal too if there is a chance that you need to specify bigger numbers
- If you can apply the above and use a fixed number of characters for each parameter (pad hexadecimals with zeroes to get a fixed length), then you no longer need the hyphen delimiters. Just concatenate all those codes. When the URL needs to be interpreted, you'll now the length of each argument, and just split the URL in those parts.

Maybe not all of them are acceptable in your case, but even if you can use some, it will shorten your URL. And then you could still consider applying base64 encoding on it to gain a little bit more.

Comment: i appreciated the time you spend to write an anwser.

Comment: I will try to re-think my parameters as you said ...1) hexa with 6 chars  to 3.  2) recurrent parameter like on, example will be changed to a number and i will create an array to get the real value.  I was hoping an algorithm that can do this  with a word like crypt but if it's too complex to decrypt it will be counterproductive

Comment: You could have a look at [Huffman encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding). But I think that if you use the word-numbering system you'll get better results, since you use knowledge that something like Huffman coding does not have. Note that Huffman encoding produces a bit stream, which you should encode with Base64.

Comment: Thank you, I've created arrays with text and accessing to array with number make link short.Only Hex color useful have been keept  . Now my url looks like this : example.com/module/5183cb3716969691fff/name it's much better.

Comment: Good to hear it was useful.